# Java: How to remove Â character appearing before £

Tags: java, string, unicode, printing, file-writing

Whenever I print or write the £ symbol , or even do anything with it, it is always displayed as Â£ with no reason for the Â to be there. I have tried writing the character in unicode but it still resulted in this weird combination. Is there any way to remove this or stop it happening?

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("£");
    }
}
```

This is all that is printed:

[image]

Comment: Where are you printing it? It could be the screen/tool etc can't handle unicode properly.

Comment: Just to the command line, that isn't the issue because it won't work when I just System.out.println() it.

Comment: `public class GenericClass { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("£".substring(1)); } }` What does this produce for you?

Comment: That works well, ill research substring and see how i can apply that to where I need it. Thanks

Comment: @Dr3amer17 this is one of those cases where I wish StackOverflow allowed downvoting of comments. What you propose is just plain wrong. The fact that it works at all means the `£` is not encoded as expected when compiled. And your proposal fails miserably for Unicode characters that are encoded in UTF-8 in such a way that the value of the 2nd byte does not match the value of the codepoint that is being encoded. The *real* solution is to fix the encoding, not work around it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would (and did) flag as Something else > "Dangerously misleading"

Answer (score 4):

Your source file is probably UTF-8 and as such, treats £ as two 8-bit characters : Â£

For portability, you have to use escaped unicode sequences in your string literals like this.

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("\u00A3");
    }
}
```